# What is the difference between a material in which the Rashba effect occurs that is not a topological insulator, and one is a TI?

Tags: quantum-spin, topological-insulators

I am working on topological insulator (TI) materials and I always have trouble understand the time reversal symmetry, spin orbit coupling in TI.

As to my understanding, the TI material property originates from strong spin orbital interactions, the so called [Rashba effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashba_effect). However, there are other materials such as thin film gold (Au) that also have the Rashba effect, but their band structure is different from TIs. Therefore, what is the difference between the materials with Rashba effect that are not TI and the TI materials?

Comment: If you read Kane and Mele's original paper about TI in graphene, they found that the required spin-orbit coupling to have TI is NOT the Rashba type. In fact, Rashba spin-orbit coupling destroys TI. What is needed in many cases is called the band inversion.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Do u mean that the band inversion in TI is not because of Rashba effect? Then what cause the band inversion in TI?

Answer (score -1):

spin-orbit or maybe tensions, pressures or relativistic effects. Any time-reversed perturbation causing a smooth deformation on band gap to be closed in case of TR-TI. it's a simple concept. we are classifying hamiltonians. A map from BZ to bloch hamiltonians space, thus classifying maps